# How can I disable this message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called "rails3-jquery-autocomplete" ( https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete )

It's working fine:) But there's one thing that I want to disable.

When I type something into an input field, and there's no matching record, it always show the message that's saying "no existing match"

I want to disable this message. Is it possible?
I wish I could see inside of its source code to customize but I cannot :(

Anyone can help me about this?
This might be piece of cake for someone but not for me.

For your information, I've done this command below

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

and after this it created some js files into `public/assets` folder

Comment: Why don't you see source? It's here: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js , string 61

Comment: Visit the source link https://github.com/gfaraj/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/commit/cde7e9477f237ef80321284f9c4b4375d740b77d

Comment: I saw the source and tried to change `label: "no existing match"` to `label: ""` but it didn't work:(

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no way to pass option into the control, but I assume this might be a trick to solve your problem.

Instead of returning empty array(from backend) when no search results, try to return a array with one result has empty id and label might solve your problem, so in your rails controller, there will be something like this:

```
def autocomplete_action
    result = do_the_search 
    if result.count == 0
      result = [{ id: "", label: "" }] # !! do the trick here
    end

    respond_with result # assume you have "respond_to :json" in your controller
end
```

---

**Here is why I am doing this:**

The reason why I think this might work is because if no result return, the autocomplete control will build a fake record with id equals to empty represent **no result**.

```
 if(arguments[0].length == 0) {
    arguments[0] = []
    arguments[0][0] = { id: "", label: "no existing match" } // hacked here
 }
```

But I do think this definitely not the **right** way to solve this problem, but for now it's workaround to solve your problem quickly.

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: thanks for an answer:) Am I supposed to add your action to the controller which is using this auto complete?

Comment: I'm using this auto complete for community search so I'm only having this 1 line in communities_controller.rb `autocomplete :community, :title, :full => true`

Comment: I think you can do this in the block `autocomplete :community, :title, :full => true do |result|
     # try to do it here
  end`